# Assume $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, derivable on $(a,b)$. $f(b)\gt f(a)$

Tags: calculus

Assume $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, derivable on $(a,b)$. $f(b)\gt f(a)$, $c=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. Then there must hold one of the claims:

1.$\forall x\in[a,b] $, $f(x)-f(a)=c(x-a)$
2.$\exists \xi \in (a,b), f'(\xi)\gt c$.

---

Well I think the way is that if we deny one then another must hold.
So I choose to deny 2.
Now if $\forall x,f'(x)\le c$ , we will claim it must hold $f'(x)=c$. Suppose there is a $\eta$ such that $f'(\eta) \lt c$. Denote $F(x)=f(x)-f(a)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)$. So $F'(x)=f'(x)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\le 0$. But $F(a)=F(b)=0$ and $F(x)\neq0$.Hence $f'(x)=c$ and it follows 1. holds.
Now was I make it strictly. I'm not sure I had give a strict proof.

Answer (score 0):

If the first statement holds, then we have $$f(x)=cx-ac+f(a),~~~\forall x \in [a,b].$$
Thus, $$f'(x)=c,~~~\forall x \in (a,b),$$ which contradicts the second statement. Therefore, the second statement does not hold.

Now, let's repeat the fact by logical language. Denote the first one as $A$, the sencond one as $B$. We have already showed that $A \to \bar{B}.$ Thus, $B \to \bar{A}.$In one word, $A$ and $B$ contradict each other.

But can you prove $\bar{A} \to B$ ? Let's try it. Notice that $\bar{A}$ states that:

$$\exists x_0 \in [a,b],s.t.f(x_0)-f(a)\neq c(x_0-a)$$

If $f(x_0)-f(a)> c(x_0-a),$ then by Lagrange mean value theorem, we have $$\exists \xi \in (a,x_0), s.t. f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_0)-f(a)}{x_0-a}>0,$$ which implies $B$.

If $f(x_0)-f(a)< c(x_0-a),$ then by Lagrange mean value theorem, we have $$\exists \xi \in (x_0,b), s.t. f'(\xi)=\frac{f(b)-f(x_0)}{b-x_0}>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=c,$$ which implies $B$.

We are done！